# Mock a property with a private setter using NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, mocking, nsubstitute

I have a class

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int MyProperty1 { get; private set; }
   public int MyProperty2 { get; private set; }

   public MyClass(){}
   public MyClass(int myProperty2) => MyProperty2 = myProperty2;
}
```

in my unit tests i need to change the value of MyProperty1 before making my assertion like below

```
[Fact]
public void MyTest()
{
   var fake = NSubstitute.Substitute.For<MyClass>(3);
   fake.MyProperty1.Returns(5);

   //Assertion
}
```

However I am getting the error

```
Outcome: Failed
    Error Message:
    NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToNoLastCallException : Could not find a call to return from.
```

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). My first question is why are you trying to do that? What are you actually trying to test?

Answer (score 1):

NSubstitute can [not stub non-virtual members of classes](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/#substituting-infrequently-and-carefully-for-classes) (see [How NSubstitute Works](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/how-nsub-works/) for an explanation). I strongly recommend adding the [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) package to any test project that references NSubstitute, as this will provide compile-time warnings when an attempt is made to substitute a non-virtual method.

With `Property1` updated to `virtual` the test works as expected:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual int MyProperty1 { get; private set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; private set; }

    public MyClass() { }
    public MyClass(int myProperty2) => MyProperty2 = myProperty2;
}
```